# prepopulated observableArray in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js and have worked through the examples on their webpage. A relevant example for my work is the [Ajax todo list](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) one where the entries of a list are sent  back and forth between the browser and a server.

I am trying to build a website with a comment list.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: comments, visible: comments().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeComment">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I could use an observableArray object and have knockout create the whole ul-list, when loading the site. However I also want the site to work without javascript and ajax (so that search engines can index it and users without javascript can use it). 
Thus it would be better, if the site could be loaded from the server with some already existing comments as html. But I'd like knockout.js to treat the existing comments in the same fashion as newly added ones, i.e. I want all li-elements to be part of the comments-observableArray, even the ones that were loaded from the server as html. Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't 'mix' knockout data source and html.
But you can show your html and then use knockout to show the dynamic comments.

You can add the new items to the comment observableArray in Ajax the callback function.

**Init bindings**

```
var vm = {
    comments : ko.observableArray([...])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**Server callback function**

```
var ajaxCallback = function(items){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(items,  function(item){
        vm.comments.push(item);
    });    
}
```

May be you could generate a script on the server that initialize the comments array on client side.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That's a pity, but your answer gave me another idea: I could prepopulate the list in html and additionally send all necessary data for knockout. If javascript is available, I can remove all previous items from the list and use the observableArray data.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this I pre-populate my observables with JSON and pass the same JSON to the server-side for rendering. The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<input data-bind="value: title" value="{{title}}" />
```

I use NodeJS / Handlebars, but this could be done with any number of server side / templating combinations. E.g. PHP / Smarty.